# How can I have a conditional on cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a Haskell library which exports several modules. I compile that library with both `GHC` and `GHCJS`. I'm using `stack` to build the library. One of those modules depends on `reflex-dom`. The issue is that I am not able to compile `reflex-dom` on GHC due to not being able to link `gtk+3` on OSX. As such, I'd like to exclude that library if the compiler is `GHC`. How can I achieve that?

```
exposed-modules:
  MyLib.Foo
  MyLib.Bar
  MyLib.App.Backend.Reflex
  MyLib.App.Backend.Gloss
  ...

build-depends:
    base ...
    reflex-dom >= 0.2 && <0.3
```

Comment: It is possible to do this. However, it is *strongly* recommended that your API be independent of conditionals in your cabal file, since it is not possible for other library writers to depend on the values of conditionals. In particular exposing or not exposing a module is part of your API.

Comment: So how do I solve this issue? I'd have to have a whole new project, "MyLib-GHCJS-stuff", just for the things that can't be compiled on the main one, with GHC. That does not seem right at all. Ideally the compiler would just be a choice of a backend target, it shouldn't reflect on the organization of the project.

Comment: Right, you would have a package that was portable and a package for the non-portable stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you may not want to do this, the way to do this is described in the "configurations" section of the cabal user manual:

https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#configurations

In particular, you should be able to write the relevant sections as such:

```
exposed-modules:
    MyLib.Foo
    MyLib.Bar
    MyLib.App.Backend.Reflex
    MyLib.App.Backend.Gloss
if !impl(ghc)
  exposed-modules:
    OtherModule

build-depends: etc, etc, etc
if !impl(ghc)
   build-depends: etc1, etc2
```